# Copy input field's value to multiple hidden fields... but with same ID's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

1) I have 3 input radio buttons with unique values. 
For e.g.

```
<input type="radio" id="id1" value="This is first value" />
<input type="radio" id="id2" value="This is second value" />
<input type="radio" id="id3" value="This is third value" />
```

2) Next, I have 2 hidden form like this:

```
<form action="//mysite.com/process1.php"><input type="hidden" id="uniqueid" value=""></form>

<form action="//mysite.php/process2.php"><input type="hidden" id="uniqueid" value=""></form>
```

3) Based upon whichever radio button the user clicks, I need to copy its value to the value of **both the above forms hidden field**.

For e.g. If user clicks on radio with id1, then it's value "This is first value" should be copied to both the forms hidden field.

**CONSTRAINTS:**
1) Have to use javascript or jquery, no server side processing available.
2) Note: both the final forms have one input field, but with same id. This is a constraint.
3) Why? Because based on some other actions on the page, the user gets to see one of the 2 forms. The only difference between them is their action is unique. All fields are same.

**WHAT I HAVE SO FAR:**
Using this, I am able to copy the value from the radio button to a hidden field's value, but it only copies to a field with a UNIQUE ID.

```
var $unique = $("#unique");
$("#radio1").keyup(function() {
$unique.val(this.value);
});
$("#email").blur(function() {
$unique.val(this.value);
});
```

Can someone guide as to how can the value be copied to multiple input fields, but with same id's?
(Yes, the id's of the initial radio buttons can be unique.)

Comment: just from your title, `id` shouldn't be same for two elements.

Comment: How ironic `uniqueid` is duplicate? It should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Having two HTML elements with same ID is an error.**

You cannot treat this as a constraint, this is NOT a valid HTML code and it will cause inconsistent behavior in different browsers.

Use classes instead:

```
<form action="//mysite.com/process1.php"><input type="hidden" class="uniqueid" value=""></form>

<form action="//mysite.php/process2.php"><input type="hidden" class="uniqueid" value=""></form>
```

And javascript:

```
var $unique = $(".uniqueid");
```

However, I couldn't find any `#radio1` or `#email` in your code, are you sure you have the right selectors?

My recommendation for the JS will be: (**[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/haf5tj2t/)**)

```
var $unique = $(".uniqueid");
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    $unique.val(this.value);
});
```

**Notes for jsFiddle:**

- I've used click event instead of keyup (don't really understand why you used keyup here..).
- I've given all radio buttons the same name so they will cancel each other out when selected.
- I've turned the hidden fields to text so you could see the result.

Comment: This is exactly what I found on some other question. :) Using classes instead of id's...

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="//mysite.com/process1.php"><input type="hidden" class="uniqueid" id="uniqueid" value=""></form>

<form action="//mysite.php/process2.php"><input type="hidden" class="uniqueid" id="uniqueid" value=""></form>

var $unique = $("input[type=hidden].uniqueid");
$("#radio1").keyup(function() {
    $unique.val(this.value);
});
$("#email").blur(function() {
    $unique.val(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by others, `id` must be unique. Try using a `data-attribute`:

```
<form action="//mysite.com/process1.php">
 <input type="hidden" data-shouldupdate="true" value="">
</form>
<form action="//mysite.php/process2.php">
 <input type="hidden" data-shouldupdate="true" value="">
</form>
```

Now you can use that attribute as selector to do something like:

```
$('[data-shouldupdate]').val(this.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all other who posted that `id` have to be unique to have correct HTML document. So if it's possible I strictly recommend you to fix the HTML document to remove all duplicates.

I write my answer only for the case that *you can't remove id duplicates because of some reason* and you still have the same requirements. In the case you should change the line

```
var $unique = $("#uniqueid");
```

to

```
var $unique = $("*[id=uniqueid]");
```

The selector `*[id=uniqueid]` (or just `[id=uniqueid]`) works slowly as `#uniqueid`, but it allows you to get **all** elements with the specified `id` attribute value. So it works even in case of id duplicates on the HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is to give a same name to both inputs. Check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/7tfLbx5u/) to see a working example. The code used is the one given is below: 
**HTML**:

```
<input type="radio" name="copiedValue" id="id1" value="This is first value" />
<input type="radio" name="copiedValue" id="id2" value="This is second value" />
<input type="radio" name="copiedValue" id="id3" value="This is third value" />

<form action="//mysite.com/process1.php"><input name="uniqueid" id="uniqueid" value=""></form>
<form action="//mysite.php/process2.php"><input name="uniqueid" id="uniqueid" value=""></form>
```

**jQuery/javascript**:

```
$("input:radio[name=copiedValue]").click(function() {
    $("input[name=uniqueid]").val($(this).val());
});
```

The radio-buttons should have the same name. I removed the type="hidden" so u can see it working correctly.

Hope it useful!